# What's the difference between Erlang Actors, Scala Actors and the theoretical concept "Actor"?

Tags: scala, erlang, akka, actor

As I know, Actor model is a theory about concurrency. Erlang and Scala both implement this theory model, but neither of their implementations are totally conform with the Actor model.

From the perspective of computer scientists, what are the differences between the concept "Actor" in Erlang, Scala and that theoretical model?

Comment: this maybe helpful https://rocketeer.be/articles/concurrency-in-erlang-scala/

Comment: I think it would help more if you ask about specific differences that you perceive. Also, what do you mean by "actors in paper"?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing expression. I want to know the differences in computer science terms.

Comment: @KumarSaurabh: Thats an excellent article, which basically describes Erlang from year 2006, and Scala Actors. I think it could do a recent comparison between `Erlang 18.x` vs `Akka 2.4.x`

Comment: In order to avoid confusion, maybe it's worth to explicitly talk about Akka actors when you refer to Scala actors, as there used to be a Scala Actors API up until v2.9 but it was deprecated in 2.10 in favour of Akka actors. See `Introduction` paragraph in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest difference is the implementation, I am not sure if it qualifies. In Erlang you have few properties:

- processes does not share memory, therefore an error in a process cannot directly overflow to another processes
- the garbage collection is working on a single process at a time, there is not global VM lockup

These are for me the major differences why I think Erlang's actor model is superior to other systems, including Scala.

On the more practical approach, quite often Scala's actor implementation is good enough for the use case. There are few use cases though (maintaining tight latency requirements, for example needing to have the same latency for p99 as p50) where your only option is to use Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang 'processes' have their own heap and the GC is optimized for actor model as it is very inherent to the VM and language design. But unlike Java, it is missing a JIT.